# Responsive menu not expanding in footer

Tags: customization

I added a footer menu to my child theme of Twenty Twelve. The menu works fine on a wider screen, but when I minimize or look at it on a mobile device and it formats as a button, clicking on the button does not expand the menu as it does in the header. I've add the code based on several tutorials I found online. The code in footer.php is this:

```
<nav id="footer-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
        <button class="menu-toggle"><?php _e( 'Menu', 'twentytwelve' ); ?></button>
        <a class="assistive-text" href="#content" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Skip to content', 'twentytwelve' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Skip to content', 'twentytwelve' ); ?></a>
        <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'secondary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) ); ?>
    </nav><!-- #footer-navigation -->
```

In functions.php I added this:

```
function mychildtheme_setup() {  
  register_nav_menu( 'secondary', __('Footer Menu', 'twentytwelve') );
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'mychildtheme_setup', 11 );
```

You can [view my site here](http://www.eileenburns.org).  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

In 'js' directory in your child theme create file "navigation-footer.js" and paste following code:

```
/**
 * Handles toggling the footer navigation menu for small screens
 */
( function() {
    var nav = document.getElementById( 'footer-navigation' ), button, menu;
    if ( ! nav ) {
        return;
    }

    button = nav.getElementsByTagName( 'button' )[0];
    menu   = nav.getElementsByTagName( 'ul' )[0];
    if ( ! button ) {
        return;
    }

    // Hide button if menu is missing or empty.
    if ( ! menu || ! menu.childNodes.length ) {
        button.style.display = 'none';
        return;
    }

    button.onclick = function() {
        if ( -1 === menu.className.indexOf( 'nav-menu' ) ) {
            menu.className = 'nav-menu';
        }

        if ( -1 !== button.className.indexOf( 'toggled-on' ) ) {
            button.className = button.className.replace( ' toggled-on', '' );
            menu.className = menu.className.replace( ' toggled-on', '' );
        } else {
            button.className += ' toggled-on';
            menu.className += ' toggled-on';
        }
    };
} )();
```

Add this code to functions.php:

```
function more_scripts_styles() {
    // Adds JavaScript for handling the footer navigation menu hide-and-show behavior.
    wp_enqueue_script( 'twentytwelve-footer-navigation', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/navigation-footer.js', array( 'jquery' ), '20140711', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'more_scripts_styles' );
```